# What is the best way to apply to all indexes after getting the attribute value in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

**Thing you want to do**
After obtaining the maximum value of the cube's Y vector, move the ico sphere by the maximum value

In the image below, the maximum value of the cube's y-axis vector was saved using the **store named attribute node**.

[image]
[image]
[image]

After that, I sent the obtained value to the set position node.

(By the way, this is off topic, but if there is an optimal solution to what I am about to say, please let me know.
If you want to apply the value saved with store named attribute node from a different node tree, first join the two nodes, select only the geometry to be moved with the set position boolean, and get the boolean value to be moved each time. is troublesome. Do you have any good ideas? )
[image]
[image]

Even if I send the value of y vector, it does not work.
That's because the index of the ico S you are trying to run is 0 to 11.
cube does not have vector data for its index value.
[image]

I thought honestly.
Trying to get the desired index value,
I was able to run ico S using the sample index node.
[image]

However, I think it might be possible to make the process simpler.
As far as I can think, if you use store named attribute node and cupture attribute node, you cannot pass the value to the index that is joined later.
It would be possible to just output a numerical value that does not depend on the node, but I think that would be less readable when the node becomes complex.
Ideally, you could use a store attribute node to insert and remove values at any time.
Is there any better way?

Comment: why don't you set position (offset) for the ico sphere before joining?

Comment: I don't want to mess with the ico sphere's position information because I want the position information to depend on the cube's y-axis maximum vector.
Is this answer correct?

Comment: I don't know... it is not clear for me. Also why are you using the vector max in statistics node (instead of y value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing it is not totally clear for me.

Though, I'd do either:

Take the max Y and move the sphere before joining:

[image]

Or mark the sphere with true, join and move it after that:

[image]

---

If you want to store the value, store it on the sphere itself, so that the cube won't have any offset:

[image]

---

Complements:

In your first image, the named attribute has no value for the sphere (or exactly this is (0, 0, 0) vector), so it won't move.

In your last image, it works because you're sampling index 0 from the original cube.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
The reason why I am particular about the store attribute node is that when I do many things with the geomtry node, I want to avoid drawing tangents (lines that connect nodes) as much as possible.
Although it is easier to read when grouped, I feel that it is a pain to go into the directory.
Sorry for asking a question that was difficult to understand. I'll be careful in the future.

Comment: I don't think this is a good practice to store (one unique value) only for "nodes drawing" reasons... storing is for associating values to something and this is not needed in your case. And as you said in your question, you need to sample in this approach, so that you'll need a 'tangent' anyway.

Comment: Of course I know it's not necessary in this case. I'm making the assumption that I need a geomtry that joins the maximum value of the y-axis vector to about 5.
I will ask this question when I actually hit the wall.
thank you.